# Can't connect Node and Phantom with custom User-agent values

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, pipe

I have the code that work on **Phantom.js** only with custom User-agent values. But when I'm trying to wrap this code by **[npm phantom](https://npmjs.org/package/phantom)** for **Node.js** I've got a problem with setting value of User-agent. As I understood from module description it should be smth like this **p.page.set('settings', { ... })**

It doesn't work even with exemple code:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create(function(ph) {
  return ph.createPage(function(page) {
    return p.page.set('settings', {userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36'});
    // or p.page.set('settings.userAgent', 'Mozilla ....');
    return page.open("http://www.google.com", function(status) {
      return page.evaluate((function() {
        return document.title;
      }), function(result) {
        console.log('Page title is ' + result);
        return ph.exit();
}); }); }); });
```

Where should I insert this code - after **phantom.create** or after **ph.createPage** and why it return me an error

```
stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
ReferenceError: p is not defined
```

Comment: What is the code you use to declare and assign to `p`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just **page.set** not **p.page.set** between **ph.createPage** and **page.open**

```
return ph.createPage(function(page) {    
  page.set('settings.userAgent', "Mozilla/5.0 ... Safari/537.36");
  return page.open("http://www.google.com", function(status) {
```